# What should be used to translate the values ​of the model columns?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.1 and I want to make a site that will support multiple languages. Static page elements I translated using the tag:

```
{% trans %}
```

using

```
i18n
```

Please tell me what I need to use to add a translation to the values ​​of the model columns, preferably manually, for example:

product_name: 'pencil'

And in the Russian version it would be 'карандаш'

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: `trans` and `i18n` are for texts inside your app (words in templates, error messages, email templates and so on) - not for models, not for database contents. For models you probably need to use some 3rd-party package which will add additional models or columns.

Answer (score 0):

This app is awesome just for that.
You may translate the model fields in the admin interface and more cool features.

https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation